# How to use deeplearn.js in a React component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg, deeplearn.js

I am currently working on creating a project with react and deeplearn.js, and have reached a roadblock when combining the two. In my react application I am importing [this deeplearnjs library](https://github.com/PAIR-code/deeplearnjs/tree/master/models/squeezenet) model which I am using to do classification. Unfortunately, when I try to call the predict() method I get the following error:

`TypeError: _this.variables is undefined`

For the following part of code:

```
SqueezeNet.prototype.predictWithActivation = function (input, activationName) {
   var _this = this;
   var _a = this.math.scope(function () {
      var activation;
      var preprocessedInput = _this.math.subtract(input.asType('float32'), _this.preprocessOffset);
```

When I use the generated Javascript in a normal HTML it works perfectly, so I am unsure why I am getting this error within react. I have a feeling it has to do with stricter React rules or Javascript versioning, but I am not sure.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

The simplest way to reproduce this is the following:

1. Create a new React app with `create-react-app`
2. Run `yarn add deeplearn` and `yarn add deeplearn-squeezenet`
3. Modify App.js to the following:

   ```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
   import {ENV, Array3D} from 'deeplearn';
   import {SqueezeNet} from 'deeplearn-squeezenet';

   class App extends Component {
     constructor() {
       super();
       var net = new SqueezeNet(ENV.math);
       net.load();

       var img = new Image(227, 227);
       img.src = 'boat.jpg';
       img.onload = function () {
         var pixels = Array3D.fromPixels(img)
         var res = net.predict(pixels);
       };
     }
     render() {
       return (
         <div></div>
       );
     }
   }

   export default App;
   ```
4. Download the following file into the public folder: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PAIR-code/deeplearnjs/master/models/squeezenet/cat.jpg
5. Run `yarn start`

For reference I am using react 16.2.0

Comment: The error message obviously means that the `variables` property on `_this` is undefined. As you say it works fine in a normal HTML page, it's likely a question of scope and how you are calling this code. However, you haven't given us much to go on code-wise. Could you update your question with the minimal steps to reproduce this error.

Comment: I updated the original question! I can't tell whether it is an issue on my end, the library end, or simply the combination with react. Thank you!

Comment: When I follow the steps above, I get one warning logged to the console: `Line 15:  'res' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars`. As you are rendering an empty div in the component's `render` function, nothing is rendered to the screen.

Comment: Yeah that warning is fine, I'm not rendering the output yet. I forgot to add the step to run it, I use `yarn start` and rendering the page causes the error above.

Comment: I followed those steps and that still doesn't produce any kind of error :( React runs just fine and renders an empty div to the page.

Comment: Ah I see, I missed a step, you have to download an image first. I changed the source to 'cat.jpg' and then put the following file in the public folder: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PAIR-code/deeplearnjs/master/models/squeezenet/cat.jpg. Sorry for the hassle but thank you for looking into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is presumably failing because some of the method calls are asynchronous (`.load()` for example).

Here is how you would make your example work with React:

1. Create a new React app with `create-react-app`
2. Run `yarn add deeplearn` and `yarn add deeplearn-squeezenet`
3. Add [cat.jpg](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PAIR-code/deeplearnjs/master/models/squeezenet/cat.jpg) to the `public folder`
4. Modify `App.js` as below

   ```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
   import { ENV, Array3D } from 'deeplearn';
   import { SqueezeNet } from 'deeplearn-squeezenet';

   const math = ENV.math;
   const squeezeNet = new SqueezeNet(math);

   class App extends Component {
     constructor() {
       super();
       this.state = {
         statusText: 'Loading Squeezenet...'
       }
     }

     buildSuggestions(obj){
       return Object.keys(obj).map(
         key => `${obj[key].toFixed(5)}: ${key}`
       );
     }

     imageLoadHandler(e) {
       const img = e.target;
       squeezeNet.load()
         .then(() => {
           this.setState({ statusText: 'Predicting...' });
           const pixels = Array3D.fromPixels(img);
           const result = squeezeNet.predict(pixels);
           this.setState({ statusText: '' });
           squeezeNet.getTopKClasses(result, 5)
             .then((obj) => {
               this.setState({ statusText: this.buildSuggestions(obj) });
             });
         });
     }

     render() {
       const text = Array.isArray(this.state.statusText)?
         this.state.statusText :
         [this.state.statusText];

       return (
         <div>
           <img src="cat.jpg"
                alt="cat"
                onLoad={this.imageLoadHandler.bind(this)}
           />
           <div id="result">
             { text.map(el => <div key={el}>{el}</div>) }
           </div>
         </div>
       );
     }
   }

   export default App;
   ```
5. Then run `yarn start`

Comment: Ah this works perfectly thank you for your patience and answer! Is the .then() syntax and arrow function the correct way to handle asynchronous calls for react?

Comment: No worries :) The `.then()` syntax is part of a wider Promise syntax (see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) This is one way of dealing with asynchronous calls. Another would be using callbacks and yet another would be using `async ... await`